# Gettings Date from the NSString ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

My string contains ::

```
 [{"temperature":"96.800003","date":"2015-11-26 18:44:42","random_id":"-1963708530","temp_type":"0","drugsymptom_value":""}]
```

**Requirement** :
How can i get only the date value from the above string

Comment: your string is static or dynamic ...

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1**

convert your JSON String to Simple string just like

```
 NSString *yourString = [{"temperature":"96.800003","date":"2015-11-26 18:44:42","random_id":"-1963708530","temp_type":"0","drugsymptom_value":""}];

 NSData *jsonData = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 // your yourString is started with array not a Dictionary
NSArray *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:nil error:nil];

// now you have Date String
 NSString *DateSTring  = dict[0][@"date"];
```

**Step-2**

your string as

```
 2015-11-26 18:44:42
 yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

 NSDate *finaldate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:DateSTring];


 NSLog(@" finaldate %@",finaldate);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would trasform it in a JSON first, then you can use `NSDateFormatter`.